# Blazor Server app - Some services are not able to be constructed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor-server-side, dbcontext

I am trying to write a simple Blazor Server app (which I have done before) and I am getting a 'System.AggregateException' error when the app tries to build.

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: CrispyAcers.Services.IFarmService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: CrispyAcers.Services.FarmService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[CrispyAcers.Models.FarmContext]' while attempting to activate 'CrispyAcers.Services.FarmService'.)

This is my Program.cs:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<FarmContext>(option =>
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("FarmConnection")));

builder.Services.AddTransient<IFarmService, FarmService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

This is the `FarmService` I am trying to add:

```cs
public class FarmService : IFarmService
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<FarmContext> dbFactory;

    public FarmService(IDbContextFactory<FarmContext> context)
    {
        dbFactory = context;
    }

    public List<Animals> GetAnimalsList()
    {
        using (var context = dbFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            return context.Animals.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I could very easily be missing something simple which hopefully someone will catch. If I remove the `FarmService` the app builds fine. I have tried Scoped, Transient, and Singleton lifetimes but nothing different happens.

Comment: Any concern that why you need `IDbContextFactory`?

Comment: That is just the only way I have ever done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For `IDbContextFactory<FarmContext>` service**

You need to register the service of `IDbContextFactory<FarmContext>` type.

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<FarmContext>(opt =>
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("FarmConnection")));
```

**For `IDbContext<FarmContext>` service**

Alternatively, you should use the `IDbContext<FarmContext>` service instead of `IDbContextFactory<FarmContext>`. Modify the `FarmService` as below:

```cs
public class FarmService : IFarmService
{
    private readonly IDbContext<FarmContext> _context;

    public FarmService(IDbContext<FarmContext> context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<Animals> GetAnimalsList()
    {
        return _context.Animals.ToList();
    }
}
```

---

**Reference**

[Database access - ASP.NET Core Blazor Server with Entity Framework Core (EF Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-7.0#database-access)

Comment: AHHHH I was just using AddDbContext, good catch! Now im getting and issue with the connection string I think. I appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome. I also amended my answer to provide `IDbContext<FarmContext>` way.

Comment: Wonderful! May I ask what the reason/advantage/difference is between the IDbContextFactory and IDbContext?

Comment: You may refer to the link I attach to the answer. But the key point for using `IDbContextFactory` is for multiple threads operations. *If there's any chance that multiple threads may access the same code block, inject a factory and make a new instance per operation. Otherwise, injecting and using the context is usually sufficient.*

Comment: That makes a lot more sense why we use Factory at work. This app will only ever be ran locally so there would be no need for it. Thanks again for the help!